# How do I enable ES6+ syntax in WebStorm?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm and ES6+ syntax. How can I make WebStorm recognize ES6+?

For example, 'let'.

Comment: `let` is ES6, not ES7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need plugins for this. Just make sure to set `JavaScript language version` (`Settings|Languages & Frameworks|JavaScript`) to either `ECMAScript 6` or `JSX harmony`

Comment: Might as well add this as a quick fix in the Editor. It'd be fast and useful!